# Alternative to error_get_last()

Tags: php

I'm trying to debug a php script that is running on my university's server.  The current version of php installed is `5.1.6`.

It is my understanding that `error_get_last()` will only work for versions `>= 5.2`.  I'm trying to echo error details for a failed `mkdir()` call which I'm sure is caused by the permissions of one of the directories involved.  I'm hoping that the error message will shed some light on the matter but I can't find a way to view the error details and I don't think that I can even access the other php error logs to check there either.

What are my other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to make your own error handler:

```php
# temporary error handler 
function tempErrorHandler($errNo, $errStr, $errFile, $errLine, array $errContext) {
    # continue to practice @ suppression
    if (0 === error_reporting()) {
        return false;
    }
    # throw it
    throw new ErrorException($errStr, 0, $errNo, $errFile, $errLine);
}

# make this the error handler for now..
set_error_handler('tempErrorHandler');

# use a try..catch
try {
    mkdir('../directory with some permission problem../../');
}
catch (ErrorException $e) {
    # echo it out
    echo $e->getMessage();
    # or do whatever you want with it: this part is just an EXAMPLE
    $errMsg = $e->getMessage();
    $isPermissionDenied = strpos($errMsg, 'Permission denied');
    if ($isPermissionDenied) {
        # do something
    }
}

# revert to previous error handler
restore_error_handler();
```

Please take note of the comment `# or do whatever you want with it: this part is just an EXAMPLE` --I'm not sure what error you get at version `5.1.6`, so you can just play around with it..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can access the error message within the scope of the error back to php4 with the $php_errormsg reserved variable. if you are not using a user defined error message handler (see [http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.phperrormsg.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.phperrormsg.php)) for more details.